# Unity Launcher icon size slider jumps back to default

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

Until I updated from 14.04 to 14.10 I could set the unity "Launcher icon size" on the Look tab under Appearance under System Settings (red cogwheel/spanner icon on the sidebar by default).

I have the Launcher icon size slider (definitely running Unity 3D), but if I move it, it immediately jumps back to the default 48.

Any ideas how I can enable icon size changes? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was because the `~/.config` directory was not belonging to me. So the fix was:

```
sudo chown <username> ~./config
```

and trying again.

Comment: you can use `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config`

Comment: mark it as best answer if it solved your problem, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing and using either unity-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

or compiz-config-settings-manager

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings-manager
```

You can use either one of these to adjust the icon size.

In unity-tweak-tool, choose the launcher tab and if you use ccsm the option is available under the options for the unity-plugin.

Comment: Ah, thank you, running the ccsm made it obvious that it couldn't change things because my .config directory was belonging to root (must be some effect of trying repairs after the 14.04-14.10 upgrade).